# Usage of future.boxed() fails with lifetime error when having nested structs

Tags: rust, lifetime

```
use futures::{future::BoxFuture, FutureExt}; // 0.3.6

struct Inner {}

impl Inner {
    async fn foo3(&self) -> Result<u32, ()> {
        Ok(8)
    }
}

struct Outer {
    i: Inner,
}

impl Outer {
    fn foo4(&mut self) -> BoxFuture<'static, Result<u32, ()>> {
        self.i.foo3().boxed()
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e69d9ee707d3f836d483259422b4e7c6):

```
error[E0759]: `self` has an anonymous lifetime `'_` but it needs to satisfy a `'static` lifetime requirement
  --> src/lib.rs:17:16
   |
16 |     fn foo4(&mut self) -> BoxFuture<'static, Result<u32, ()>> {
   |             --------- this data with an anonymous lifetime `'_`...
17 |         self.i.foo3().boxed()
   |         -------^^^^---------- ...is captured and required to live as long as `'static` here
```

I notice that I can specify a lifetime for `BoxFuture`; instead of passing `'static`, what else can I pass to make this code compile?

Comment: [Please don't edit your question to change it after you've received answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64459/281829), especially if those edits invalidate answers. If your question didn't ask what you needed, then ask a new question, link to the previous one, and describe what the exact difference(s) are.

Answer (score -1):

As the error message states:

> `self` has an anonymous lifetime `'_`

Match the lifetime of the return type with the lifetime of the argument:

```rust
impl Outer {
    fn foo4(&mut self) -> BoxFuture<'_, Result<u32, ()>> {
        self.i.foo3().boxed()
    }
}
```

This is equivalent to

```rust
impl Outer {
    fn foo4<'a>(&'a mut self) -> BoxFuture<'a, Result<u32, ()>> {
        self.i.foo3().boxed()
    }
}
```

This specific case doesn't require boxing, so I'd write

```
impl Outer {
    async fn foo4(&mut self) -> Result<u32, ()> {
        self.i.foo3().await
    }
}
```

See also:

- [`'_`, the anonymous lifetime](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/ownership-and-lifetimes/the-anonymous-lifetime.html)
- [Lifetime Elision in *The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html#lifetime-elision)

Comment: I see. Thanks. I tried '_ and this code compiled. However, my real issue is still not solved. The example code I provided here is a stripped down version of what I am trying to accomplish. 

With '_ the code compiled, but in my "real application", the error is now showed in the outer layer of code.

I have a Outer2 { o: Outer; futures_list: FuturesOrdered<BoxFuture<'static, Result<u32, ()>>  } ... When I try to push the future returned by foo4 into the futures_list ... I get a new compilation error.

With '

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8754d4d988348d321d2256befb512e5e

Comment: @user855 that's an iteration on [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/155423). You can't do it.

Comment: So, what is the workaround ... Where do I store this future? The reason I want to store it because I want to tokio::select! on that future with other futures ... What coding pattern do I follow?

Comment: Am I doomed? Can I not write this program in Rust? @shepmaster

Comment: I will try to write my application with this pattern instead -- https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ab4e5e55f75a0703957257e618f49306